# Variable / Dynamic number of cells in table row - always fill the width

Tags: html, css

How can I make a table with multiple rows that have different number of columns (but not always the same number .... columns can be added and removed dynamically) but still have the cells in each row take the full width of the row?

Of course, I'd like to use only CSS and avoid a Javascript solution.

Here is an example of my issue:

```css
table{
border: solid;
}

td{
background-color: black;
color: white;
}

.fullWidth{
/* width: 100%; doesn't work */
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>
cell 1
</td>
<td>
cell 2
</td>
<td>
cell 3
</td>
<td>
cell 4
</td>
<td>
Cells are added and removed dynamically
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='fullWidth'>
this cell should be the full width of the table
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

EDIT: I was trying to keep the question short and to the point, so I left out most of the details. :P

I am using a table because I am using [Bootstrap's responsive tables on a jQuery Datatable](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/styling/bootstrap.html), and I need to insert a custom row to add details to some of the rows. (Bootstrap's responsive tables already utilizes the default "child" row feature of `Datatables`, or I would have just used that)

Comment: I don't think you can, that's what the `colspan` attribute is for. You could try using `tr { display: flex; }` but that's probably going to mess up table behavior you might expect. Does it have to be an html `table`? This is easy in flexbox.

Comment: You need to use the `colspan` attribute if you want a cell to cross more than one column. If the rows are going to vary widely in the number of columns, I'd recommend not using a table in the first place.

Comment: Don't use a table for this... check out flexbox. Tables aren't very dynamic or responsive. Thats why people don't use them for layouts anymore (and because they should have never been used for layouts in the forst place lol)

Comment: Ok, I left out the reason I'm using a table in the first place. Please check the recent question edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the comments, what I'm asking isn't possible with CSS alone. I'm going to open a new question to address the Javascript solution with bootstrap responsive tables.

So the answer to the question on this page is: **no, it is not possible**.

EDIT: as long as you set the colspan correctly on the first inserted row, it looks like bootstrap's responsive table takes care of the rest.